# Multithread program in java

Tags: java, multithreading

My code gives me a problem.

My code throws `IllegalMonitorStateException` in `setStr` which is in Hoge class.

I change `Hoge.class` into `this` in `setStr`. My code correctly finished!

But why did it finish normally?

```
    public class Sample {
        static Hoge gh = new Hoge();
        static Hoge gh2 = new Hoge();

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            new Thread() {
                private Hoge h2 = gh;
                public void run() {

                    System.out.println("start initialize");
                    h2.setStr("BazzBazz");
                    System.out.println("end   initialize");

                    System.out.println("start thread 1");
                    System.out.println(h2.getStr("thread-1"));
                    System.out.println("end   thread 1");
                }
            }.start();

            new Thread() {
                private Hoge h2 = gh2;

                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("start thread 2");
                    System.out.println(h2.getStr("thread-2"));
                    System.out.println("end   thread 2");
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }

    class Hoge {
        private String fuga = "fugafuga";

        public void setStr(String str) {
            synchronized(Hoge.class) { //<-HERE ! change "Hoge.class" into "this".
                fuga = str;
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        String getStr(String suffix) {
            synchronized(Hoge.class) {
                return suffix+ fuga;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your`setStr` method should be like this:

```
public void setStr(String str) {
            synchronized(Hoge.class) { //<-HERE ! change "Hoge.class" into "this".
                fuga = str;
                try {
                    Hoge.class.wait();//call wait on Hoge.class 
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

You should use `Hoge.clas.wait()` instead of `wait()`. Why?
Because , as specified in [oracle documentation about wait()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) :

> **This method should only be called by a thread that is the owner of
>   this object's monitor.**

i.e a `thread can't invoke a wait on an object until it owns that object's lock`. Otherwise it will throw [`IllegalMonitorStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html) . Here , you are acquiring lock on object of `Class` of Hoge(i.e Hoge.class) called as `class level lock` , but was calling `wait` on the current object of `Hoge`(`this`). So it was leading to `IllegalMonitorStateException`. That's why your code was working fine when you acquiring lock on the current object (`this`) because `wait()` in that case was called on the current object (`this`) itself.

Answer (score 2):

Because `this` in `gh` and `gh2` are different, `this` is an instance of Hoge.

So when use `Hoge.class`, there is noly one synchronized lock, rather than using `this` which will use two different lock.